# How to work in other directories via a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I already searched stack overflow, but there was nothing suitable for my problem.
What I wanted to do:

I have a directory:

```
~/data/project/bin
```

In this directory is my script firstScript.sh. I want it to do 3 things:

1. get into directory: ~/mytest
2. take every file in there
3. and use a command on it (for example cat)

To realize the first Step I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74780/how-to-execute-script-in-different-directory) and tried this (used ls -l as command to see if the right directory was found):

```
#!/bin/bash

#step 1 get into the directory
#setp 2 loop through all files
#step 3 add the command

cd /mytest ls -l

#also tried:
# cd ~/mytest ls -l
```

nothing happened, so I tried the path and command by myself in the console/terminal and it is the correct path for sure. Any Idea what is wrong with this? Also tried this with ./relativ/path, but this didnt work as well.

Comment: Your code misses the tilde symbol. Besides you must separate different commands with a semicolon or with a newline: `cd ~/mytest; ls -l`

Comment: yeah i see, the error message does not appear anymore, but ls -l is not executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get into directory: ~/mytest `cd ~/mytest`
2. and use a command on it (for example cat) `cat`
3. take every file in there `cat *`

`cd ~/mytest; cat *`

Comment: thanks, and sry for that easy question but I am totally new to this.

Comment: Just browse this site up and down and use the search. You'll learn.

Comment: I did use the search... I even liked what I thougt could be the solution.